# It's not working only with Chrome.(asp.net, visual studio, c#)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, caching, pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());

     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

     Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10));     

     Response.Cache.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
}
```

It work IE, Microsoft Edge. but It's not work with Chrome 
When i click F5 in browser. 
The time is changed every time when i click F5 even before 10seconds
only in the chrome.
Anyone know about this? help me plz.
sorry i dont speak english very well. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Why does Google Chrome NOT use cached pages when I define the HTTP "Expires" header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881408/why-does-google-chrome-not-use-cached-pages-when-i-define-the-http-expires-hea)

Basically, it's because Chrome is designed that way.

If you look at the headers sent TO your server on refresh, they should include one that tells you the time the browser has a cached file for.
(can you post them here?)
You can look at that time, and either send a new response, or send back a 304 Not Modified response to get the browser to use the cached file.

EDIT:
In Chrome, press F12 to open the Developer Tools
Goto the "Network" tab at the top
Press F5 on the page you want to reload.
Go back to the network tab and press Stop
In the "Name" column, find the page you are wanting to find out about and click on it.
In the section to the right will be a "Headers" tab.
On that tab will be the Request and Response headers.

Comment: If you look at the headers sent TO your server on refresh, they should include one that tells you the time the browser has a cached file for. (can you post them here?)  --> i don't know how to see it. sorry im just beginner... i don't know how to do it